# clicking on links after closed iframe not available

Tags: javascript, iframe, href

have `index.html`, and opening iframe with content of other page `"test.html"` on top of it.
iam closing iframe, just changing url at the moment

JS:

```
  function confirmCloseIframe() {

            doIt = confirm('wanna close Iframe?');

            if (doIt) {
                window.location = "/index.html"
            }
        }
```

links of index.html behind this iframe are not more clickable.
do you now why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats because your iframe is still an overlay since you haven't moved/removed the iframe from your actual page content...therefore they are not clickable.

You need to either move the iframe or remove it or hide it.